# Retornar a través de java una consulta con alias sin que traiga errores

Tags: java, json, oracle

me encuentro retornando en java una consulta realizada a través de Oracle con la función max .

```cs
public IEnumerable<Cliente> lastRegister()
        {
            List < Cliente > ultimo = new List<Cliente>();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string query = "select max(Idcliente) as ultimoID from cliente";
            dt = bd.ExecuteQuery(query);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow x in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Cliente c = new Cliente();
                    c._idCliente = int.Parse(x["ULTIMOID"].ToString());
                    ultimo.Add(c);
                }
            }
            return ultimo;
       }
```

el tema es que en C# como es mi controlador principal si me lee el ALIAS que le puse a la consulta, pero al consumirlo desde JAVA no me lo lee y me retorna null, se me cae en al atribuirle en el for a int.

```java
public List<Cliente> lastCliente(){
        globalURL +="/ultimo";
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = Conectar(globalURL);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP Error code : "+ conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
            String output;
            String jsonRespuesta="";

            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonRespuesta=output;
            }
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonRespuesta);
            List<Cliente> xl = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);
                int lastID = e.getInt("ULTIMOID"); // ME DICE QUE NO ENCUENTRA EL OBJETO ULTIMOID.
                xl.add(new Cliente(lastID));
            }
            return xl;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClienteDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Aqui les dejo la excepción que me entrega.

```
Grave:   org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["ULTIMOID"] not found.
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:454)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getInt(JSONObject.java:514)
```

Intente probarlo con el nombre original de ID y no me funciono, me sigue trayendo null.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que ULTIMOID te llega como Integer en vez de como Long? ¿Has depurado a ver que tenes en el objeto e?

Comment: @ordago si, me llega como int, pero me trae todos los campos de la entidad cliente como null, no creo que eso sea el error